# Facebook Connect - Post Status

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have just about got the Facebook connect working on my site. I am able to log in and PHP has all the users details. I would now like to post a status when a user logs in with the Facebook connect.

I have searched everywhere on how to do this, tried lots of code. And I'm still unable to get anywhere with it. Please be very specific with me as I am new to the Facebook Connect.

Comment: A pop-up box? Which other sites were you thinking of / what exactly do you want to do? I read your question as "when the user logs into my site, automatically post 'John Doe is using hartswebsite.com!' on their wall". What would the pop-up box contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're looking for the Javascript Facebook SDK. More info about publishing to the stream through javascript can be found at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this, from [the documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api), on the `Publishing` section?

> You can publish to the Facebook graph
>   by issuing HTTP POST requests to the
>   appropriate connection URLs, using an
>   access token on behalf of the user or
>   an application access token (for Open
>   Graph Pages). For example, you can
>   post a new wall post on Arjun's wall
>   by issuing a POST request to
>   https://graph.facebook.com/arjun/feed

EDIT

Snipped from [this part of the documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api):

> If you have an authenticated user with
>   the publish_stream permission, and
>   want to publish a new story to their
>   feed:

```
var body = 'Reading Connect JS documentation';
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { body: body }, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would i make this appear as a pop up box, like on other Facebook connected websites? I'm really confused.

Comment: @hart1994 As Jasper said below, to make the popup appear you'll need to use the Javascript SDK. I've posted the relevant snippet and the link on my answer. :)

Comment: I think the code you pasted works when you already have the extended permissions to post to the feed, while the FB.ui function will always ask the user for permission. Depends on the situation which one to use when.